# Controlling an interactive process with PHP using Symfony Process

Tags: php, shell, symfony, process, symfony-process

I am trying to control the systems [ssh-agent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) by adding new keys to it using [ssh-add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add). For this I'm using the [Symfony Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) component.

When I run this code from a web site it works perfectly fine but when I run the same code in a shell/console the ssh-add process hangs on `Enter passphrase for <path to key>:`

A simplified version of the code looks something like this

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$keyPath = '<path to key>';
$keyPassword = '<password for unlocking the key>';
$socketPath = '<path to ssh-agent socket>';

$sshAdd = new Process(
    "ssh-add {$keyPath}",
    null,
    [
        'SSH_AUTH_SOCK' => $socketPath
    ],
    $keyPassword
);
$sshAdd->run();
```

As you can see in the code above I make a call to `ssh-add`, sets the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the environment so `ssh-add` can talk to the agent and then sends the password in the input. As I said previously, when I run this in a web context it works but it hangs in a shell/console context.

I did an `strace` of when running in the console and the relevant parts looks like this

```
open("<path to key>", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(4, "<key password>", <length of password>)      = 20
close(4)                                              = 0
wait4(9650, 0x7fff00ab3554, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL)   = 0
select(8, [5 7], [], [], {0, 0})                      = 0 (Timeout)
wait4(9650, 0x7fff00ab3554, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL)   = 0
select(8, [5 7], [], [], {0, 0})                      = 0 (Timeout)
select(8, [5 7], [], [], {0, 200000}Enter passphrase for <path to key>:) = 0 (Timeout)
select(8, [5 7], [], [], {0, 200000})                 = 0 (Timeout)
select(8, [5 7], [], [], {0, 200000})                 = 0 (Timeout)
select(8, [5 7], [], [], {0, 200000})                 = 0 (Timeout)
select(8, [5 7], [], [], {0, 200000})                 = 0 (Timeout)
...
```

As you can see the write seems to be ignored and the `ssh-add` program starts to block waiting for input.

Comment: Are you nesting commands?  that question is expecting input from the user, but it is blocked behind your wrapping process.  You will need to find a way to perform the underlying command non-interactively.

Comment: I dont think the ssh_add process is blocked since I can enter the password manually. It is more that the PHP script cannot enter the password for the user since ssh_add has moved to the foreground and the PHP script just sits around waiting for the process to finish.

Comment: What are fd's 5 and 7 to that process? Where does fd 4 get opened? Does running the script from the shell with `< /dev/null` (and possibly `2</dev/null`) help it to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found a solution to this problem after reading the source for ssh-add and by reading [this very old article from Wez Furlong](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2004/may/pty-support-for-proc-open-in-php-5/) where he talks about adding PTY support to PHP.

To quote the article:

> What this does is similar to creating a pipe to the process, but instead creates master (for your script) and slave (for the process you're running) pty handles using the /dev/ptmx interface of your OS. This allows you to send to, and capture data from, applications that open /dev/tty explicitly--and this is generally done when interactively prompting for a password.

Turns out Symfony Process also supports PTY so the original code only needed a couple of changes. First I need to specify I want to use PTY instead of pipes by calling `setPty(true)`. Then I need to simulate that the user has pressed *ENTER* after inputting the password simply by appending a line feed to the input.

The final code would look something like this (with comments on the changed lines)

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$keyPath = '<path to key>';
$keyPassword = '<password for unlocking the key>';
$socketPath = '<path to ssh-agent socket>';

$sshAdd = new Process(
    "ssh-add {$keyPath}",
    null,
    [
        'SSH_AUTH_SOCK' => $socketPath
    ],
    $keyPassword . "\n"   // Append a line feed to simulate pressing ENTER
);
$sshAdd->setPty(true);   // Use PTY instead of the default pipes
$sshAdd->run();
```